# ADO.NET database application run time Exception

Tags: c#, ado.net, sqlconnection, sqlcommand

Help please with understanding what these exceptions telling me and how I can resolve them?

I've created an application with ADO.NET. The project debugger don't show any errors, though, during run time I receive these exceptions. I guess I am messing some lines of code I wrote in the 'PersonkartotekDBUtil.cs file, inside this method 'GetFullContactPersonTreeDB'. 
Here what I am trying to do is to show a full person overview info with connecting properties of Person directory through JOIN principles.

Can anyone correct me please?

The method that I suspect not being functional is:

```
public void GetFullContactPersonTreeDB(ref Person fcpt)
    {
        string fullPersonkartotek = @"SELECT  Person.PersonId, Person.FirstName, Person.MiddleName, Person.LastName, Person.Email, Person.Notes, Person.PrimaryAddress, Person.AlternativeAddresses, Person.TelefonNumbers
                                          Address.AddressID, Address.StreetName, Address.HouseNumber, Address.PostNr, Address.PersonPrimary, Person.AlternativePerson
                                          PostNr.PostNrID, PostNr.PostNumber, PostNr._Country, PostNr._City
                                          City.CityID, City.CityName,
                                          Country.CountryID, Country.CountryCode, Country.CountryName,
                                          Telefon.TelefonID, Telefon.Number, Telefon.TelefonType, Telefon.TelefonProvider, 
                                          Provider.ProviderID, Provider.ProviderName

            FROM      Person INNER JOIN
            Address ON Person.PersonId = Address.Person INNER JOIN
            Telefon ON Person.PersonID = Telefon.Person
            AlternativeAddress ON Person.PersonID = AlternativeAddress.Person
            Address ON Person.PersonID = Address.Person
            WHERE   (Person.PersonID = @PersonId)";


    }
```

The Error message on the console window after running the program:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near
>   '.'.    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean
>   isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean
>   shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry,
>   SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()    at
>   Infrastructure.PersonkartotekDB.ADONET.PersonkartotekDBUtil.GetFullContactPersonTreeDB(Person&
>   fcpt) in
>   C:\Users\User\Desktop\E18I4DABHandIn2au2016082168\Personkartotek\Infrastructure\PersonkartotekDB.ADONET\PersonkartotekDBUtil.cs:line
>   382 ClientConnectionId:716d2899-cbbe-4aa6-89de-66452d907b66 Error
>   Number:102,State:1,Class:15
>
> Unhandled Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect
>   syntax near '.'.    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean
>   isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean
>   shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry,
>   SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()    at
>   Infrastructure.PersonkartotekDB.ADONET.PersonkartotekDBUtil.GetFullContactPersonTreeDB(Person&
>   fcpt) in
>   C:\Users\User\Desktop\E18I4DABHandIn2au2016082168\Personkartotek\Infrastructure\PersonkartotekDB.ADONET\PersonkartotekDBUtil.cs:line
>   449    at ApplicationLogic.PersonkartotekApp.ProgramApp() in
>   C:\Users\User\Desktop\E18I4DABHandIn2au2016082168\Personkartotek\ApplicationLogic\PersonkartotekApp.cs:line
>   14    at ProgramApplication.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   C:\Users\User\Desktop\E18I4DABHandIn2au2016082168\Personkartotek\ProgramApplication\Program.cs:line
>   10

The attachment shows the exception on the debugger. [image]

Comment: Please do not expect us to go dig in github to get the code. Post the relevant code in the question body.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question with the relevant code.

Comment: Ok, that's better. but you only posted the stack trace, what's the error message?

Comment: That is the problem that it says not much. It throws this error among others. C:\Users\User\Desktop\E18I4DABHandIn2au2016082168\Personkartotek\Infrastructure\PersonkartotekDB.ADONET\PersonkartotekDBUtil.cs:line 378 at ApplicationLogic.PersonkartotekApp.ProgramApp() in

Comment: You would need to catch the error message.

Comment: how would i do that? In a try catch block? But does the INNER JOIN of the classes properly initiated?

Comment: You need to post the exception type and message, not just the stack trace. You can also call `ToString()` on the the Exception instance.

Comment: When I run the program on the console window I get this error that I pasted. I tried to put the  using(){} block inside a try catch block. but it didn't help much.

Comment: Then I think you missed text in your copy paste because it should **not** start with the word at

Comment: arent you missing some commas in your select statement? Just after "Person.TelefonNumbers", "Person.AlternativePerson" and "PostNr._City"?

Comment: I added comma at the end of each line except the last one. Provider.ProviderName. But now I receive error "Incorrect syntax near AlternativeAddress".

Comment: You probably have a double comma there

Comment: You need to learn how to do your own debugging. Capt your query to SSMS and debug it there, then copy it to code once it works.

Comment: I attached the debugger image. Not sure what this window of debugger telling me exactly.

Comment: Copy the query into SSMS. Brake the columns list in the select so that each column will be in a different row. Check visually if you see something suspicious. If not, declare the `@PersonId` variable and try to run it directly on SSMS. If you get an error message, double click it. This should move the caret roughly to where the problem is.

Comment: I solved the issue by adding INNER JOINs in between those table, which I had used only one. Thanks to SSMS, which helped me generate the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you were missing several commas and also missing an Inner join.

By running your query in Sql server management studio(SSMS) and using parse(CTRL+F5) you can highlight the problem.

Please see fixed code below.
In future it's worth having consistent formatting to make your life easier.

```
SELECT  Person.PersonId, Person.FirstName, Person.MiddleName, Person.LastName, Person.Email, Person.Notes, Person.PrimaryAddress, Person.AlternativeAddresses, Person.TelefonNumbers,
                                      Address.AddressID, Address.StreetName, Address.HouseNumber, Address.PostNr, Address.PersonPrimary, Person.AlternativePerson,
                                      PostNr.PostNrID, PostNr.PostNumber, PostNr._Country, PostNr._City,
                                      City.CityID, City.CityName,
                                      Country.CountryID, Country.CountryCode, Country.CountryName,
                                      Telefon.TelefonID, Telefon.Number, Telefon.TelefonType, Telefon.TelefonProvider, 
                                      Provider.ProviderID, Provider.ProviderName

        FROM      Person 
        INNER JOIN Address ON Person.PersonId = Address.Person 
        INNER JOIN Telefon ON Person.PersonID = Telefon.Person
        INNER JOIN AlternativeAddress ON Person.PersonID = AlternativeAddress.Person
        INNER JOIN   Address ON Person.PersonID = Address.Person
        WHERE   Person.PersonID = @PersonId
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) It helped.